# TFS 2017 does not assign build agents to build tasks

Tags: tfs, build, agent

I think something in my TFS 2017 is locked. The builds will no longer be assigned to the build agents.

Build not starting:
[image: Build not starting]

Agents available:
[image: Agents available]

Information:
- TFS2017 running on Windows 10.
- Build agents running on same machine.
- SQLEXPRESS Database was full (10G cap), since then no more builds.
- I backed the database up and migrated to SQL Standard to solve the full database.

What I tried:
- Unconfigured the agents and reconfigured them.
- Deleted the default agent pool and got a new one, reconfigured the agents again.

Problem: 
- Though two build agents are available, the builds are still not getting build.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue when stop the service "`Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent`"

So, please check if the service "`Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent`" is running on TFS app tier.

If it's not running, just start it.

[image]

Comment: It was running, but a restart of that service helped. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

Did you reconfigure the capabilities of your new Agents so that the Demands can be met ?

The error seems German, so would be great if you can translate that.

Comment: It is German. That was the last build that startet, there is no error in the picture. It just says: "Waiting for agent". Please explain what you mean by capabilities of the agents.

Comment: On the right of  your 2nd screenshot, there is a tab where you can configure the agents capabilities.
In your build definition you can define "demands" have a look and see which demands it has. Your agent must match all Demands with its capabilities in order to accept the build.

Comment: Do the system capabilities shows VisualStudio and VSTest items as well ?

Comment: Yes, it does. Both are shown in demands as well as capabilities.

Comment: Check the permissions of the new pools you created, do your build service account have the right permissions ?
Also perhaps you can see something in the _diag folder on the Agent's installation folder.

Comment: The permissions are correct. The only thing fishy in the logfiles is: "[2017-09-07 13:01:25Z INFO MessageListener] No message retrieved from session '7664ba37-bcdb-4a78-bbaa-7bfa1f444a65' within last 30 minutes."

Comment: only thing else i can think of right now is the Agent pool selection in the build definition, did you update that to the new agent pool you created ?

Comment: Yes, I did update that, too. I think the problem has something to do with the SQL Express database reaching its limits before migrating. But I don`t know what else to try.